# Zend - error in index.php - not opening Zend/Application.php

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework, ubuntu

I have a project written in PHP, in zend framework. But when i go on page: localhost/Project/public, i get an error:

```
Warning: require_once(Zend/Application.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/Project/public/index.php on line 18 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Zend/Application.php' (include_path='/var/www/Project/library:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/Project/public/index.php on line 18
```

The line 18 in file index.php is following:

```
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
```

I have set include_path in php.ini:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/usr/local/ZendFramework/library"
```

Zf project is successfully creating by commands from console, so i think that Zend is well configured (anyway in php.ini).

Help me! What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the include path it's using in the error, and it doesn't include `/usr/local/ZendFramework/library`. Typically `index.php` overrides the include path to point it at the project's library folder. So either you want a copy of ZF in the library folder, or if you prefer to keep ZF in `/usr/local/` you want to edit this include path to point at `/usr/local/ZendFramework/library` as well.

Comment: Thanks man! I copied the folder Zend to library in my project and it works : ). thanks again, I greet